# .gitignore file got cached

Tags: git, command-line, gitignore

I have problems with my .gitignore file not ignoring directory that I set in it.

on my mac I run:

- `git status` It show long list of files in .idea directory

> new file:   .idea/[file name]

- `git config core.excludesfile` and It shows me the correct .gitignore file.

I also been trying to run:

```
git rm . -r --cached .
```

This is my .gitignore file:

> .idea/

Any idea what else can I do. I need to perform a commit and I do not want to commit everything.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your .gitignore file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you already added those files to git (they are tracked, that's why git says "new file". otherwise git would say: "untracked files".. this does not mean they are committed, but ready to be committed). To untrack them:

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

I think the easiest thing for you to is to untrack all files:

```
git reset HEAD .
```

then add only the files that you will track.

**more info** .gitignore works only for files that are not tracked!

Comment: ? what do you mean; if you want them to be in .gitignore you don't want to track them, I suppose? if you ignore them; they will not show up and you cannot add them by accident.

Comment: git allows you to add files that are ignored with -f option